# Domain Driven Design - Retrieve information related to an entity from data base after the entity has been created

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am new to DDD and struggling to find the correct way to solve a simple problem.

Let's say I have am working on a project where I am processing credit cards using a third party API that has the ability hit a credit card terminal or use saved credit cards to process a payment.  I have a `payment` entity, a `request` entity and a `token` entity.  `payment` has attributes like `payment_date`, `amount`, etc as well as the `request_id`.  A `token` can be used to bypass the credit card terminal.  It refers to a previously used credit card, who's information is stored with the credit card processing company.

When processing refunds, I need to know the id of the credit card terminal that was used when the payment that is being refunded was made.  This is stored in the requests table in the database unless a token was used and the credit card terminal was not needed.  The `token` entity has a `source_request_id` attribute that points back to the request that created it.  It can get the id of the credit card terminal from that record.

The corresponding database tables look something like.

```
tblPayment.id
tblPayment.amount
tblPayment.payment_date
tblPayment.request_id

tblRequest.id
tblRequest.terminal_id
tblRequest.token_id

tblToken.id
tblToken.source_request_id
```

It doesn't seem to make sense to take the performance hit to always query the database for the terminal id, when creating the `payment` entity, especially if a token was used.

I could add a `getTerminalId` method to the `payment` entity that would pull `request` and `token` entities from their repositories and use those to find the terminal id.  From what I understand, that breaks the rules of DDD though.

Using DDD, how should I get the terminal id for the `payment`?

Comment: DDD isn't a coding methodology.  Database query techniques are orthogonal to TDD design.

Comment: How much slower was the three-table solution? If it was too slow, you can  test moving the token info to the request table (or perhaps look into other DBMSs).

Comment: I ended up adding `origin_terminal_id` as attributes of `payment` and `token`.  The performance penalty should be pretty limited.  I think I was over complicating things. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 3):

> I could add a getTerminalId method to the payment entity that would pull request and token entities from their repositories and use those to find the terminal id. From what I understand, that breaks the rules of DDD though.

Exactly what DDD rule do you think you're violating here?

The only rule I know this violates is encapsulation (which predates DDD). Getters do not provide encapsulation (despite reports to the contrary). All they do is let you set break points that tattle when someone gets. They let anyone get the info the same as if the field was public.

The alternative is sometimes called [Tell, don't ask](https://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask). Following this rule you'd stop asking `Payment` for a Terminal Id with `getTerminalId()` and tell Payment you're processing a refund with `payment.refund()`. You'd pass payment the minimal it needs to know to do the rest of this work and you'd trust it to do the rest. Exactly how it does this will depend on which payment implementation this is but you don't need or want to know that. That's something else's problem.

What if the info you need is scattered? Send the command through everywhere that has the info you need gathering it up as you go. When you have enough to do something do it and be done with it. No need to make the caller manage any of this. Doing this works well when you make dependencies explicit so you don't have to guess when something is in a good state and ready to work.

Am I saying all getters are evil and wrong? No. But I know the trouble they cause is subtle at first. It's easy to just live with it and start grabbing what you need as soon as you find it.  But some day you'll want to change things and find you can't because it seems like everything knows about what you want to change. It's tempting to take the easy path. It's not easy to come back from it.